# Cannot get value from table cell trough htmlunit when that value is number

Tags: java, html-parsing, htmlunit

I'm trying to parse html from page: http://www.hidmet.gov.rs/latin/prognoza/stanica.php?mp_id=13274 and cannot get value from table cell if that value is number.

```
\\\Tried by xpath: 

DomText dt = page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"sadrzaj\"]/div/table[1]/tr[4]/td[4]/text()"); \\ getting null

\\\Tried by reference:

String dt = (HtmlTable) page.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"sadrzaj\"]/div/table").get(0).getBodies().get(0).getRows().get(3).getCells().get(4).getTextContent();\\ getting null
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I'm trying to get value from table cell;
`code
<tr>
<td class="levo">&nbsp;Maks. temperatura: (&deg;C)</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="text-align:center">35</td>
<td style="text-align:center">28</td>
<td style="text-align:center">28</td>
<td style="text-align:center">29</td>
<td style="text-align:center">33</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath is wrong (misses /tbody).

```
DomNode dt = page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"sadrzaj\"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[4]/text()");
System.out.println(dt);
```

produces here 22.
You can use page.asXml() to get the correct Dom structure.